# Inspect the .tfrecords file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I created the images.tfrecoreds file using following code

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import glob

images = glob.glob('E:\Projects/FYPT/vehicle/bus/*.jpg')

def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

tfrecords_filename = 'E:\Projects/FYPT/vehicle/images.tfrecords'

writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecords_filename)

original_images = []

for img_path in images:
    img = np.array(Image.open(img_path))


height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]

# Put in the original images into array
# Just for future check for correctness
original_images.append((img))

img_raw = img.tostring()

example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'height': _int64_feature(height),
    'width': _int64_feature(width),
    'image_raw': _bytes_feature(img_raw)
    }))

writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

writer.close()
```

Then I tried to Inspect the output of the tf.TFRecordReader() by printing the output of the "serialized_example"

```
import tensorflow as tf
import skimage.io as io


reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
tfrecords_filename = 'E:\Projects/FYPT/vehicle/images.tfrecords'
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([tfrecords_filename],num_epochs=10)
_,serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

sess= tf.Session()
print(sess.run(serialized_example))
```

but it gives me following warning and not give any output of the "serialized_example" [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIuF5.png) is the screen shot of the command line

What is the mistake have I done and how should I print the output of the "serialized_example"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that warning, because you are using `tf.train.string_input_producer()` which returns a queue, but input pipelines based on `QueueRunner API` are deprecated and not supported in future versions.

**Queue-based solution - not recommended!**

`serialized_example` is just a string object (the same that was written with the `tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter` to `images.tfrecords` file for each example).

You need to parse each single example to get its features. In your case:

```
features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example,
                                   features={"image_raw": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                                             "height": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64) }

img_raw = tf.image.decode_jpeg(features["image_raw"])
img_height = features["height"]

# initialize global and local variables
init_op = tf.group(tf.local_variables_initializer(),
                   tf.global_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)

  # start a number of threads
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

  try:
    while not coord.should_stop():
     img_raw_value, img_height_value = sess.run([img_raw, img_height])
     print(img_raw_value.shape)
     print(img_height_value)
  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
     print("End of data")
  finally:
     coord.request_stop()

  # wait for all threads to terminate
  coord.join(threads)
  sess.close()
```

**Dataset API - highly recommended!**

A detailed description how to build a input pipeline can be found [here: TensorFlow API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data#_QueueRunner_).

In your case you should define a `_parse_function` like this:

```
def _parse_function(example_proto):
  features={"imgage_raw": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            "height": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            "width": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}

  parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)

  img_raw = tf.image.decode_jpeg(parsed_features["img_raw"])
  height = parsed_features["height"]
  width = parsed_features["width"]

  return img_raw, height, width
```

Than create a dataset that reads all of the examples from TFRecord file, and extract the features:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([tfrecords_filename])
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
# here you could batch and shuffle

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

next_element = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess: 
  while True:
    try:
      val = sess.run(next_element)
      print("img_raw:", val[0].shape)
      print("height:", val[1])
      print("width:", val[2])
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
      print("End of dataset")
      break
```

I hope this helps.